# Tried using this code to implement razorpay payment gateway (link generation API) in Bot framework in C#

Tags: c#, json

I tried using this code to implement razorpay payment gateway in Bot Framework using C#, but I'm getting an error

> "code":"BAD_REQUEST_ERROR",
> "description":"amount: cannot be blank.",
> "metadata":[], "reason":null, "source":null, "step":null

Please check the following code:

```
var client1 = new RestClient("https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payment_links/");
client1.Timeout = -1;

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic cnpwX3Rlc3RfWklxSU16Q2pBbXZKOVE6UTEzSmRDcEh3SURUR1RkNWlsUFpyASVF");

var body = @"{" + "\n" +
            @"  ""amount"":10000," + "\n" +
            @"  ""currency"": " + paymentRequest.currency.ToString() + "," + "\n" +
            @"  ""expire_by"": 1691097057," + "\n" +
            @"  ""reference_id"": " + paymentRequest.reference_id.ToString() + "," + "\n" +
            @"  ""description"": ""health renewal""," + "\n" +
            @"  ""customer"": {" + "\n" +
            @"    ""name"": " + paymentRequest.customer[0].name.ToString() + "," + "\n" +
            @"    ""contact"": " + paymentRequest.customer[0].contact.ToString() + "," + "\n" +
            @"    ""email"": " + paymentRequest.customer[0].email.ToString() + "," + "\n" +
            @"  }," + "\n" +
            @"  ""notify"": {" + "\n" +
            @"    ""sms"": " + paymentRequest.notify[0].sms + "," + "\n" +
            @"    ""email"": " + paymentRequest.notify[0].email + "\n" +
            @"  }," + "\n" +
            @"  ""callback_url"": ""https://payfctn.azurewebsites.net/api/payment?code=Pyn0cYSXWR1Gc6ocfT5HL3XEWR0al6GOkSiacWFZDad6HYjsxzKK1Q==""," + "\n" +
            @"  ""callback_method"": ""get""" + "\n" +
            @"}";

request.AddJsonBody(body);
request.AddParameter("application/json",ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client1.Execute(request);

_paymentResponseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PaymentResponseModel>(response.Content);
return _paymentResponseModel;
```

Request body in json:

```
{
    "amount": 1000,
    "currency": "INR",
    "accept_partial": true,
    "first_min_partial_amount": 100,
    "expire_by": 1691097057,
    "reference_id": "TS1989",
    "description": "Payment for policy no #23456",
    "customer": {
         "name": "Gaurav Kumar",
         "contact": "+919999999999",
         "email": "gaurav.kumar@example.com"
    },
    "notify": {
         "sms": true,
         "email": true
    },
    "reminder_enable": true,
    "notes": {
         "policy_name": "Jeevan Bima"
    },
    "callback_url": "https://example-callback-url.com/",
    "callback_method": "get"
}
```

Comment: Did you try sending the request using postman?

Comment: can you delete your authorization token, it is dangerous to put it here

Answer (score 1):

the problem i think is with your addJsonBody(body), the body is of type string, your are doing a serialize of a already serialized data. you must just give an object with normal properties and it ll be serialized by the addJsonBody
Try this code please

```
    var client1 = new RestClient("https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payment_links/");
    client1.Timeout = -1;

    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic cnpwX3Rlc3RfWklxSU16Q2pBbXZKOVE6UTEzSmRDcEh3SURUR1RkNWlsUFpyASVF");

    var body = new {
                  amount =10000,
                  currency = paymentRequest.currency.ToString(),
                  expire_by = 1691097057,
                  reference_id = paymentRequest.reference_id.ToString(),
                  description = "health renewal",
                  customer = {
                    name = paymentRequest.customer[0].name.ToString(),
                    contact = paymentRequest.customer[0].contact.ToString(),
                    email = paymentRequest.customer[0].email.ToString(),
                  },
                  notify {
                    sms = paymentRequest.notify[0].sms,
                    email = paymentRequest.notify[0].email
                  },
                  callback_url = "https://payfctn.azurewebsites.net/api/payment?code=Pyn0cYSXWR1Gc6ocfT5HL3XEWR0al6GOkSiacWFZDad6HYjsxzKK1Q==",
                  callback_method = "get"
                };

    request.AddJsonBody(body);
    request.AddParameter("application/json",ParameterType.RequestBody);

    IRestResponse response = client1.Execute(request);

    _paymentResponseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PaymentResponseModel>(response.Content);
    return _paymentResponseModel;
```